# Fluent NHibernate: How are foreign keys set with HasMany, inserted or updated?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

**A little context:**

I have many instances of `SomeCollection` which store many `Rule` information that needs to be persisted to the database. Each `Rule` in the database have an auto incremented ID (PK) and a custom `RuleId`. The `Rule` table also contaisn a foreign key, which is the ID of the collection. The `Rule` table contains a unique constraint on both `RuleId` and `CollectionId`.

---

**Question:**

1. How are foreign keys inserted into tables when mapped with `HasMany`, is it updated after the child is inserted? I ask as null is shown in the messages below, but I know the values are set
2. If the above is true or false, how can I enforce multi-column unique constraint and avoid the issue detailed below.

When I set enforce the unique constraint in `SomeCollectionMapping`, I get the following violation:

> FCE detected: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):
>   Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__supporte__4D7ABD34DC8C8A20'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.rules'. The
>   duplicate key value is (123, NULL).

The data is try inserting is:

```
123, myId1 
123, myId2
```

If I omit the lines: `part.Not.Nullable()` and `part.UniqueKey("uniqueRef")` the data is successfully inserted into both tables, but doesn't enforce uniqueness.

Even though the insert using Fluent NHibernate fails, I'm able to insert data using Microsoft SQl Server Management Studio without issues, and the multi-column constraint is working fine.

---

---

**SomeCollection.cs**

```
internal class SomeCollection
{
    public SomeCollection()
    {
        this.CollectionId = string.Empty;
        this.CollectionName = string.Empty;
        this.Rules = new List<Rule>();
    }

    public virtual string CollectionId { get; set; }

    public virtual string CollectionName { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Rule> Rules { get; set; }
}
```

**Rule.cs**

```
internal class Rule
{
    public Rule()
    {
        this.DisplayName = string.Empty;
        this.RuleId = string.Empty;
        this.MyValue = 0;
    }

    public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public virtual string RuleId { get; set; }

    public virtual int MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

**SomeCollectionMapping.cs**

```
internal sealed class SomeCollectionMapping : ClassMap<SomeCollection>
{
    private const string TableName = "some_collections";

    public SomeCollectionMapping()
    {
        this.Table(TableName);

        this.Id(x => x.CollectionId)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Column("collectionId")
            .UniqueKey("abc123");

        this.Map(x => x.CollectionName)
            .Column("name")
            .Not.Nullable();

        this.HasMany<Rule>(x => x.Rules)
            .KeyColumns.Add("collectionId", part =>
            {
                // No violations if I omit these two lines
                part.Not.Nullable();
                part.UniqueKey("uniqueRef");
            })
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

**RuleMapping.cs**

```
internal sealed class RuleMapping : ClassMap<Rule>
{
    private const string TableName = "rules";

    public RuleMapping()
    {
        this.Table(TableName);

        this.Id().GeneratedBy.Increment().Unique();

        this.Map(x => x.RuleId)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .UniqueKey("uniqueRef")
            .Column("ruleId");

        this.Map(x => x.DisplayName)
            .Column("name")
            .Not.Nullable();

        this.Map(x => x.MyValue)
            .Column("myValue")
            .Not
            .Nullable();
    }
}
```

*Nhibernate 4.1.1
FluentNHibernate 2.0.3.0
SQLServer*

Comment: Added my own answer which seems to have fixed any issues, but it doesn't really answer my main question of why. Feel free to continue contributing. Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen [this](/q/11468668/1178314)?

Answer (score 2):

Right.

After randomly trying things, i added `Not.KeyNullable()` to the `HasMany` chain. The data is now correctly inserted and no exceptions are thrown. The unique and `not null` constraints are working fine.

This appears to be a fix, but if someone else wants to answer with more detail, I will gladly receive and accept those instead.